# Does the ARP standard forbid a switch to answer for another machine?

Tags: networking

Consider a setup, where there are 2 switches with some devices behind each of them. They have the same sub net, so a broadcast goes to both parts of the network.

```
|PC1|PC2|PC3|
      |
  |Switch1|           Subnet: 255.255.255.0
      |               Broadcast: 192.168.0.255 | FFFF.FFFF.FFFF
  |Switch2|
      |
|PC4|PC5|PC6|
```

So, if Switch2 knows the MAC of PC4 and receives an ARP request from PC1, would Switch2 be allowed to answer, using it's own ARP table? I know that they don't, I traced this through a few simulations in Cisco Paket Manager. But is it the protocol that forbids it, or are the switches just not smart enough?

Answer (score 0):

If we’re strict about terminology, a switch is purely an Ethernet layer (layer 2, the data link layer) device and knows nothing about any Layer 3 (network layer) protocols such as IP.

ARP is a protocol for devices doing IP-over-Ethernet, to help map IP addresses to Ethernet MAC addresses. Since pure Ethernet switches aren’t expected to know about IP, Ethernet switches aren’t expected to know how to do ARP.

A pure Ethernet switch doesn’t have an ARP table (mapping IP addresses to Ethernet MAC addresses). All it has is a bridge table, keeping track of which MAC addresses are out which physical ports. It knows nothing about IP addresses.